# Non-friend single-line operator + overload based on operator +=

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, c++14

Let's say I have a class:

```
class A
{
    //...
};
```

With well defined `operator +=`:

```
A& operator +=(const A&) {return *this;} //class without members
```

So let's try to overload `operator+` also (as non-friend). I don't want to use class name to call constructor of temporary object (kinda want this make generic code):

```
A operator +(const A& other) const
{
    return auto(*this)(*this) += other; //error: invalid use of auto
//         /\/\/\/\/\    /\      
//        type of *this  ||
//                 constructor call
}
```

`auto` is no good here. Let's try `decltype`.

```
A operator +(const A& other) const
{
    return decltype(*this)(*this) += other; //error: 'A& A::operator+=(const A&)' discards
//         /\/\/\/\/\/\/\    /\                      qualifiers [-fpermissive] return
//          type of *this    ||                      decltype(*this)(*this) += other;
//                    constructor call                                      ^
}
```

This managed to get the type out of `*this`, but `operator+` is declared const, so we got `const A` deduced (that's what I thought). So let's go on:

```
A operator +(const A& other) const
{
    return typename std::remove_const<decltype(*this)>::type(*this) += amount; 
    //same error as previous
}
```

Now I got mindblown. Even thought I removed constness, it still discards
qualifier. Well, maybe that's because all I was doing was just CASTING. So stupid. To call a constructor I would have to generate code that (besides type) has ::Constructor (so I even tried to make an alias for constructor, but at this point I failed so hard). My broken brain gave up, but rest of my consciousness gave me an solution (which is generic in writing, so that's good):

```
// outside of class
template<class A>
inline A&& make_rvalue(A copy)
{
    return std::move(copy);
}

// inside of class
A operator +(const A& other) const
{
    return make_rvalue(*this) += other; // such generic code
}
```

That's what I ended with. But is there some trick that doesn't involve any other function call?

EDIT: I know classic methods of doing this, but what I search is described below:

- operator is reduced to `{return /*...*/;}`
- doesn't involve names of class methods or global functions
- takes to account overloads with other types - it cannot take argument(s) by value, since `class A != class B`, argument `int` over `const int&` doesn't help much with `Matrix` class (but proxy operator that calls target operator with exchanged arguments is OK)
- takes to account (possible) order of operation (`x@y != y@x`), where both should should have same return statement
- return statement should be exacly the same for given `operator@` is every class that has overloaded `operator +=`

Comment: Why not just take the argument by value in the first place, instead of const ref?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.

Comment: This `operator+` is **not** generic; it traffics in objects of type `A`. There's no good reason to avoid using the type `A`, since you know exactly what it is. And even in generic code you'd know the type that you're dealing with. All this circumlocution is pointless.

Comment: It makes sense in term of logic. You make a copy of `*this` and add to it. Nothing wrong.
@Useless Hmmm... Lol, that's perfect! Pretty much solves it, but I still would love to know if it's possible to make a non-const temporary out of const reference without calling any additional functions (constructors included). EDIT: well, that works with `A@A` operators, but what about `A+number`? Implict conversion from number to A would totally suck. EDIT2: Also, when operation A@B isn't equal B@A, then that won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
T add(T temp,const T &b)
{
    temp += b;
    return temp;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
  A operator+(const A& other) const { return add(*this,other); }
```

Comment: I know this one very well, been using that version since c++11 came out. What I search is version of `return /*...*/;`

Comment: @BlackMoses: Ok, I've changed my answer to match.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go on record as saying this whole line of thinking/coding is going the wrong way. You already know that (in this case) the return type is `A`. Your code seems to be putting a lot of work into saying `A` in the most complex, indirect way possible.

```
A operator +(const A& other) const {
    A ret {*this};
    ret += other;
    return ret;
}
```

Since you seem to really *want* to use C++11 features (even though in this case almost none of them provides any real help) I used a braced initializer, so it uses *something* from C++11. And no, this isn't one line, but it is readable.

Note that the same style is fine in generic code as well. For example, in a non-member overload of `operator+`, we might have something like this:

```
template <class T>
T operator+(T const &a, T const &b) { 
    T ret {a};
    ret += b;
    return ret;
}
```

This can be simplified a bit as well though:

```
template <class T>
T operator+(T ret, t const &b) { 
    ret += b;
    return ret;
}
```

Again, we lose precisely *nothing* from the fact that older compilers can and will accept the code without problem.

Comment: Ok, but if operator+ involves two types, and order of operation makes huge difference, think about call of possible proxy operator that invokes actual operator with swaped arguments - simple templates won't know what is a good order, and such proxy template would be exacly the same as original template, but without knowing whether its actually a proxy or not. Too ambiguous to work with.

Comment: @BlackMoses - yes, if the question was different, the answer could be different. But it's not.